# MIPS: Writing code to ask a user for an input and printing responses

Tags: loops, assembly, mips, user-input, mars-simulator

I am really struggling with assembly language and, unfortunately, have gotten into the habit of treating it more like an assignment than a learning objective.  I am now being tasked with writing some code that asks a user for an input (in this case, an integer) and then prints a response based on that integer.

Directions:
Ask a user for an integer-- if the integer is '8', print "Great!".  If it's not 8, print "Try again" and then ask them to submit one more time.  If they don't print the integer, '8', on the second attempt, simply type game over.

```
.data 
message: .asciiz "Please enter an integer:"
correct_str: .asciiz "Great!\n"
incorrect_str: .asciiz "Game over! \n"

    li $t0,8  #this is the correct answer
    li $t1,0 # creates a counter of two attempts 
loopcheck:   
    la $a0, message  # prompt user
    li $v0, 4
    syscall     
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s1, $v0    # s1 becomes what user inputs


#this is where we check to see if it's 8, printing game over or looping again and printing game over if not correct on second time

printGameOver:
    la $a0, wrong_str
    li $v0, 4
    syscall  
    j done
printright:
    la $a0, right_str
    li $v0, 4
    syscall     
done: #exit
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: *gotten into the habit of treating it more like an assignment than a learning objective*.  If you're trying to get someone to do your assignment for you, that's not how SO works.  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)  If you *are* trying to learn something this time, that's great, but I don't see a question here to answer.  It's not clear that a loop would be the easiest way because you need to do different things after the first vs. 2nd failure.  You could jump into the middle of a `do{}while()` loop structure I think...

Comment: But anyway, you need to make more of an attempt at the actual logic.  Try writing it in a language you do know so you can design the logic separately from the MIPS implementation.

Comment: The brunt of the question is more of how I should approach it correctly.  So the top piece of the code, to my knowledge, creates a register for the correct answer (this is 8).  Then, it creates a register for a counter starting at 0.  I'm not sure what the next portion is doing entirely, however, I do know that I need to check to see if the register of $s1 is equal to that of the register of $t0 which is the correct answer.  If it is, i need to print the "printright" string, and if it isnt, ask one more time and print gameover if wrong.

Comment: https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html documents MARS system calls.  You can single-step the code in the MARS debugger to see what each instruction does.  The easiest approach would be not trying to loop at all, just make another read-integer system call after printing try again for that path.  Is there one piece of that process you don't know how to implement, or are you still having trouble figuring out the logic steps?  Draw a flow-chart or write it in a high-level language for example.

Comment: You'll need branches (i.e. ````beq````, or ````bne````…), if that's the question. Show us an attempt of what you've tried so far instead of leaving that part blanc.